# Why does log4j issue warnings for overlapping classes?

Tags: maven, log4j

I have a maven project and I have this dependency in my POM.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
```

In my POM there is no "log4j-over-slf4j" defined, but it might be inherited from another dependency "org.springframework.boot". If that's the case, how to fix this warning issue?

```
[WARNING] log4j-1.2.17.jar, log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar define 29 overlapping classes: 
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.spi.OptionHandler
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggerRepository
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.NDC
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.LogManager
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.spi.ErrorHandler
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.MDC
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton
[WARNING]   - org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender
[WARNING]   - 19 more...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command `mvn dependency:tree`. This will show you all of your projects direct dependencies and their transitive dependencies. **log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25** is likely a transitive dependency of one of your direct dependencies. After you identify which direct dependency is pulling it in you can add an exclusion to your pom like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.my.dep</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-dep</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** log4j-over-slf4j might be a transitive dependency for multiple dependencies you have defined in your pom, so you will have to add this exclusion for each dependency that has log4j-over-slf4j as a transitive dependency.

After adding your exclusions, verify that log4j-over-slf4j no longer shows up in the output of the `mvn dependency:tree` command.